# A word to use sarcastically for "An invention which is amazing but not useful in any way"

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say that two people are talking about an invention which is amazing in that it is beautiful or proves an impossible concept but hardly has any use. How can one refer to it in a sarcastic manner, as if saying that the invention was the need of the day ?

Sample Dialogue -

> **Thawed out caveman :** I must say the science of your times is quite
>   amazing. I never quite could have imagined something like this.
>
> M**odern day scientist :** Yes...Modern technology has grown by leaps and
>   bounds...We have X, Y and Z
>
> **Thawed out caveman :** And then there is cloning
>
> **Modern day scientist :** Yes, truly one of our "_________"
>   technologies in this day and age of overpopulation.

Comment: 'chocolate teapot' and 'solution looking for a problem' come to mind, but don't fit your sentence.

Comment: If you hadn’t mandated sarcasm, you could have said one of our most **pointless** technologies...

Comment: with sarcasm you get to pick a word with the exact opposite meaning: useful, practical, important ...

Comment: Sorry, but voting to close as too broad and/or POB

Comment: First off, cloning is extremely useful. Soon, you will be able to go to the dentist and get a tooth cloned. Setting that aside, a classic sarcastic idiom is "we need that like a fish needs a bicycle." The idiom has an interesting history.

Answer (score 0):

**Invaluable** has the potential for sarcasm. Most dictionaries will record its primary and most commonly understood [meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invaluable):

> : valuable beyond estimation : priceless

However, note two things. First, **In-** is a prefix that negates what follows. In conventional use, **invaluable** means that it can't be valued. Yet a second meaning of the word also exists: it *has no value*. From the Oxford English Dictionary:

> 2. Without value, valueless.

Here is an [example](https://books.google.com/books?id=BtxZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=John%20Bull%20%22altogether%20invaluable%20to%20your%20Ladyship.%22&source=bl&ots=ImW78IFqJk&sig=ACfU3U2grWUMtamOavKAllUE5UZU4kfbeg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE2sv1mIfgAhWPTN8KHc03C9MQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=John%20Bull%20%22altogether%20invaluable%20to%20your%20Ladyship.%22&f=false) from a 19th century play *John Bull* by George Colman:

> I flattered myself I might not be altogether invaluable to your Ladyship.

People have played with this word to create sarcasm: sure, the superficial reading is that they're beyond value, but something about the tone and context suggests that they're not valued. A couple of other uses that strike a sarcastic tone:

> [@ disney](https://twitter.com/emmyypetes/status/1063621415507845121), thank you for making me, as well as all of my PhotoPass coworkers and friends, feel replaceable and **invaluable**. ... Saying I’m **invaluable** is sarcasm.
>
> [They](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/4384734.stm) say sarcasm is the lowest form of wit. Yeah, right. Assuming "they" are the same experts who tell us "Look before you leap" and "He who hesitates is lost", then I think we all know how incisive and **invaluable** their advice is. What would we do without it?

So your jaded modern scientist would be engaging in wordplay while subtly hinting at their true disposition towards cloning.

Comment: *Any* utterance in English can be sarcastic, especially any form of praise. This sheds no light and breaks no ground..

Comment: @Robusto Yes, any expression may be sarcastic, but not every expression has sarcasm reinforced by the word meaning two opposite things. To give an example, *valuable* does not allow for the same wordplay because *valuable* never means *useless*. *Invaluable* sometimes does mean useless. (Also, if any utterance may truly be sarcastic, and if the qualities of a word can never help with that in a punning way, then the question itself doesn't work, since no single word will do what the original poster is asking.)

Comment: If "no single word will do what the original poster is asking" then why suggest one with an extrinsic qualifier? That's not what this site is about.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but you are entitled to your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You might go for straight out sarcasm with ***productive***.

> Yes, truly one of our ***most productive*** technologies in this day and age of overpopulation.

On the one hand, it is used to describe something good:

> **2** achieving good results
>       *a **productive** partnership*
>       *Politeness is usually more **productive** than confrontation.*
>   <sub>[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/productive)</sub>

On the otherhand, it can just mean making something:

> **3** FORMAL causing or producing something
>   <sub>[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/productive)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

How about "most precious" or "most darling"? Or "sterling"? These words are all a little over the top — you know right away that if a technology is truly wonderful, you would never call it "darling."

Answer (score -1):

This is what [*white elephant*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/white+elephant) means.

> **white elephant** *n*
>   1. An expensive item that is troublesome or useless. The term comes from a story about the king of Siam, who was said to have given an albino elephant, considered sacred, to a member of the court whom he disliked, knowing that taking care of the animal would exhaust the person's fortune. *At first, Eve was excited to inherit the farm, but it soon proved to be a white elephant she couldn't afford.*

<sup>—The Free Dictionary Online</sup>

Comment: I think *white elephant* emphasises the **cost** aspects, where the question emphasises the **uselessness** of the item.

Comment: @k1eran: "1. An expensive item that is troublesome or useless." I think if you read to the end of the definition you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: I think *white elephant* is close but not quite right here. The OP’s question makes no mention that the item is **expensive**, and I think that aspect is core to the *white elephant* idiom.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion.